# Create a custom type with constraint in Go

Tags: go

How do I create a custom type in Go where only valid values can be accepted?
For example, I want to create a type called "Names" where its underlying type is a string. However it can only accept the values "John", "Rob" or "Paul". Any other value will return an error.
I've create the following program in a very simplistic way just to represent what I would like to achieve.

http://play.golang.org/p/jzZwALsiXz

What would be the best way to write this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like this (http://play.golang.org/p/JaIr_0a5_-):

```
type Name struct {
    string
}

func (n *Name) String() string {
    return n.string
}

func NewName(name string) (*Name, error) {
    switch name {
    case "John":
    case "Paul":
    case "Rob":
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Wrong value")
    }
    return &Name{string: name}, nil
}
```

Golang does not provide operator overload so you can't make the check while casting or affecting value.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to do something like this (http://play.golang.org/p/uXtnHKNRxk):

```
type Name string

func (n Name) String() string {
    switch n {
    case "John":
    case "Paul":
    case "Rob":
    default:
        return "Error: Wrong value"
    }
    return string(n)
}
```

Comment: I like the second example creating the validation as a method of "Name". Just for my knowledge, would you be able to explain what's going on behind the scenes? I understand what the code is doing but I don't quite get when the String() method is actually called. I'd like to fully understand the concept of your code.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: In go, if you want to an object to be able to be printed (i.e fmt.Printf("%s\n", obj), you need to implement the Stringer interface. You can note that if you rename the String() method from the example, it still works but without validation. It just with the String() from the underlying object (here: string).